# How to access ReactJS DOM elements using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to get the height of the `header` element using Jquery's `height()` method. **But it gives `NAN` when I console the values**

Here's my react snippet

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import $ from 'jquery'; //un-used

export default class HomepageNavigationBar extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <header className="header_area">
        <div className="main_menu">
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <div className="container">
              <a className="navbar-brand logo_h" href="index.html">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" />
              </a>
              <button
                className="navbar-toggler"
                type="button"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation"
              >
                <span className="icon-bar" /> <span className="icon-bar" />
                <span className="icon-bar" />
              </button>
              .
              .
              .
              //dots used to denote that code further exists but to make this minimal I have removed them.
        </div>
      </header>
    );
  }
}
```

and here's my external `theme.js` file

```
(function($) {
  "use strict";

  var nav_offset_top = $("header").height() + 50;

  console.log(nav_offset_top); //gives 'NAN' when console, even after I scroll

  function navbarFixed() {
    if ($(".header_area").length) {
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= nav_offset_top) {
          alert('Hi');
          $(".header_area").addClass("navbar_fixed");
        } else {
          alert('no Hi');
          $(".header_area").removeClass("navbar_fixed");
        }
      });
    }
  }
  navbarFixed();  
})(jQuery);
```

Problems are:

1)

```
 console.log(nav_offset_top);
```

this above code gives `NAN` when console the value even after I scroll the page up and down

2)

```
$(".header_area").length
```

`header_area` length is always `0` even after I scroll up and down the page

Can someone here help me out?

Comment: `"header"` is a tag lookup. that's not a single value, it's an array. add IDs and lookup by ID

Comment: I have only one header.What is lookup? how do I use it?

Comment: ?? lookup isn't a function, it's called a `verb` in english. It describes *what you are doing* in English. You are looking up elements using jQuery by **tag name**. It's the same as doing `$("div")` it doesn't matter there's only one on the page. Looking up html tags (div, span, a, etc..) always returns an array.

Comment: Also if you're even in this situation, you're probably doing something the wrong way. There is almost *never* a need to have both jQuery and React on the same site

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're getting `NaN` because you're accessing `header` when it is not yet rendered.

Put your code in `componentDidMount()` instead to make sure that elements are rendered before accessing it.

**Read more:** https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

**The docs state that:**

> Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here.

This is exactly what you're doing, accessing DOM nodes using jQuery.

```js
class HomepageNavigationBar extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    var nav_offset_top = $("header").height() + 50;

    console.log(nav_offset_top);
    
    function navbarFixed() {
    if ($(".header_area").length) {
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= nav_offset_top) {
          alert('Hi');
          $(".header_area").addClass("navbar_fixed");
        } else {
          alert('no Hi');
          $(".header_area").removeClass("navbar_fixed");
        }
      });
    }
  }
  navbarFixed();  
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <header className="header_area">
        <div className="main_menu">
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <div className="container">
              <a className="navbar-brand logo_h" href="index.html">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" />
              </a>
              <button
                className="navbar-toggler"
                type="button"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation"
              >
                <span className="icon-bar" /> <span className="icon-bar" />
                <span className="icon-bar" />
              </button>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<HomepageNavigationBar />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" style="height: 1000px;"></div>
```

Comment: Nope, he's getting NaN because he's looking up a tag, which is always an array.